# Who will the Social Security Administration be mailing out a 1099 to for my deceased mother?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, social-security, form-1099

My mother died in June of 2023. She was collecting  Social Security at the time. I am the  executor of her estate. However, I have not officially notified the Social Security administration of that.

Her estate needs to file an income tax return and I am planning on doing that. As such, I was expecting her 1099 to show up today. It has not. Will the Social Security Administration be mailing out a 1099 to her? to me?  If not, what should I  do?

Comment: 1099s are due by Jan. 31st

Comment: @littleadv I understand that 1099s are not due  yet but I have two friends on SS and they both already have their 1099s,

Comment: @Bob I'm not from the US, so don't _know_, but I'd expect such notices to be mailed over a period of time (perhaps surnames starting A to G mailed thus week; H to M next week etc.)

Comment: Their search function is not very good, but I eventually found https://blog.ssa.gov/get-your-social-security-benefit-statement-ssa-1099-2/ which has several apparently official answers saying to call the local field office in this situation. (Unlike IRS which has been working to centralize offices and facilities for decades, and even USPS which is trying to cut back because they're losing so much money, SSA takes pride in maintaining field offices 'nearby' to pretty much the whole population.)

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible that a 1099 can be generated early, most 1099's and similar tax forms will be received late in the month of January.

> As such, I was expecting her 1099 to show up today. It has not. Will
> the Social Security Administration be mailing out a 1099 to her? to
> me? If not, what should I do?

It is possible that an organization will generate a 1099 in electronic form prior to mailing out paper copies. It is also possible that no paper copy will be mailed. If they do mail it, it will be sent to wherever the address on record is.

Late in the year I get a reminder from my employer or financial company that if I have requested paper copies they will be sent to the address they have associated with my account, and I am responsible for keeping that address updated.

> I am the executor of her estate. However, I have not officially
> notified the Social Security administration of that.

That might mean the forms might go to an old address. It is also possible that the US post office can't deliver to that old address.

I assume from your statement that you have notified them of her death, but haven't notified them of your role as executor.

Comment: The Social Security Administration knows that my mother has died. Her checks have stopped coming. I have not notified them I am the executor of the estate. Should I notify  them and if so, how?